# Copy hash values from a hash into another only where keys exist in both hashes?

Tags: ruby

How can the values from one hash be copied into another, but only for the keys that exist in both hashes?

Minimal example

```rb
h1 = {a: 10, b: 20, c: 30}
h2 = {a: nil, c: nil}

## desired result
{a: 10, c: 30}
```

I've solved with a 'manual' approach - i.e. `{a: h1[:a], c: h1[:c]}` - but it's verbose and looks worse the more keys there are. I'm sure there's something (much) more elegant?

Answer (score 6):

You can do that as follows.

```
h1 = { a: 10, b: 20, c: 30 }
h2 = { a: nil, c: nil, d: nil }
```

```
h1.slice(*h2.keys)
  #=> {:a=>10, :c=>30}
```

See [Hash#slice](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-slice).

Note that the example above differs from the one in the question in that I've added a key to `h2` (`:d`) that is not present in `h1`.

Comment: I initially provided a second answer (`h2.merge(h2) { |k,*| h1[k] }`), but upon re-reading the question I saw that the OP did not guarantee that every key in `h2` appeared as a key in `h1` (though it did in the example), making that solution incorrect.

Answer (score 4):

The "manual" approach with a loop would look something like this

```
h1.each do |k, v|
  h2[k] = v if h2.include? k
end
```

If your goal is to create a new hash, rather than modifying an existing one, you can use [`filter`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Hash.html#method-i-filter) (called `select` in older versions of Ruby)

```
h1.filter { |k, v| h2.include? k }
```

Or if you want to modify `h1` to only have the keys from `k2`, you can use [`filter!`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Hash.html#method-i-filter-21) (called `select!` in older versions), which works like `filter` but modifies in-place.

```
h1.filter! { |k, v| h2.include? k }
```